# Push notification not working Android with php

Tags: php, push-notification

I am trying to send push notification to **Android** from **PHP**, I checked my project number, API key and device id/device token, all credentials are right but i am getting following error:

```
{"multicast_id":7219223859365110681,"success":0,"failure":1,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"error":"MismatchSenderId"}]}
```

Here is my code:

```
define( 'API_ACCESS_KEY', 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' );
$registrationIds = array( 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' ); //Replace this with your device token

$msg = array
(
    'message'   => 'here is a message. message',
    'title'     => 'This is a title. title',
    'subtitle'  => 'This is a subtitle. subtitle',
    'tickerText'    => 'Ticker text here...Ticker text here...Ticker text here',
    'vibrate'   => 1,
    'sound'     => 1,
    'largeIcon' => 'large_icon',
    'smallIcon' => 'small_icon'
);
$fields = array
(
    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
    'data'          => $msg
);

$headers = array
(
    'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
    'Content-Type: application/json'
);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send' );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );
$result = curl_exec($ch );
curl_close( $ch );
echo $result;
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: are you sending notification to multiple devices at a time??

Comment: can you post your code in android?

Comment: MismatchSenderId means your API key or token is wrong

Comment: @sourabhkaushik: no right now i am trying to send to one device at a time

Comment: Maybe it's time to move on from using that API instead of spending time trying to get it working? _"As of April 10, 2018, Google has deprecated GCM. The GCM server and client APIs are deprecated and will be removed as soon as April 11, 2019. Migrate GCM apps to [Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM)](http://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/), which inherits the reliable and scalable GCM infrastructure, plus many new features. See the [migration guide](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/android-migrate-fcm) to learn more."_

Comment: I agree with @MagnusEriksson its better to move to FCM asap

Comment: Check your curl, it should be **https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send** instead of **https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send**.

Answer (score 0):

try changing this

```
$fields = array
 (
'registration_ids'  => $registrationIds,
'data'          => $msg
);
```

to

```
$fields = array
(
'to'  => 'XXXXXXXXXXX',//device token
'data'=> json_encode($msg)
);
```

and this

```
$headers = array
(
'Authorization: key=' . API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type: application/json'
 );
```

to:

```
$headers = array
(
'Authorization'=> 'key='. API_ACCESS_KEY,
'Content-Type'=> 'application/json'
);
```